# How is openwrtorg/rootfs:19.07.4 actually building?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, openwrt

I have been trying to do some customization to the openwrtorg/rootfs:19.07.4 ([here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openwrtorg/rootfs/19.07.4/images/sha256-ab563374f7b7b5dd26ef96a2b181f5f722cdbceae16a3e7dfffc7d16749fd34a?context=explore)) container

The written Dockerfile is

```
MAINTAINER Paul Spooren <mail@aparcar.org>
ADD dir:2bf606039dd1f357b8d8655abcc8470848e0165b167803c02a816ae3d5d69f9b in /
EXPOSE 22 443 80
USER root
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

I don't understand how the container is being created without FROM command and second how is data being added to the container

```
ADD dir:2bf606039dd1f357b8d8655abcc8470848e0165b167803c02a816ae3d5d69f9b in /
```

what exactly is this command doing.

[Here](https://github.com/openwrt/docker) is the link to their GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Dockerfile" listing on Docker Hub isn't an actual copy of the image's original Dockerfile; instead, it shows what it's possible to extract from the `docker history` of the image.  That means that the base image(s) will be flattened into a single listing, so the whole thing implicitly starts `FROM scratch`, and anything that gets `COPY` or `ADD`ed to the image shows that hash format rather than the original file path.

The GitHub repository you link to has a [Dockerfile.rootfs](https://github.com/openwrt/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.rootfs) which should look more familiar.  I'll copy it here, with some annotations:

```sh
# Don't use any base image at all; start from an empty filesystem.
# This is the starting point for anything that unpacks a Linux
# distribution images.  All images eventually come back to this if
# you follow their FROM, and their base image's FROM, and ...
# Not shown in the Docker Hub output.
FROM scratch

MAINTAINER Paul Spooren <mail@aparcar.org>

# Copy the root filesystem into the (completely empty) image.
# The Docker Hub output just shows a hash of what got copied in.
ADD ./ /

# These are identical to the Docker Hub output.
EXPOSE 80 443 22
USER root
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

Since this is a base image – it's constructed in a similar way to the `debian`, `ubuntu`, or `alpine` images – you can build your own image by starting it `FROM openwrtorg/rootfs:19.07.4` and proceeding from there.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the link you've shared and I can see in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/openwrt/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.rootfs) that there is indeed a [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) base image being used.

Also, the command `ADD dir:2bf606039dd1f357b8d8655abcc8470848e0165b167803c02a816ae3d5d69f9b in /`

is adding an image to the root of the directory using the image ID.

Edit: Also, you cannot pull the scratch image. It can only be used as a base image as: `FROM scratch`. Most likely this is the ID for the scratch image. More info [here.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10737)

Comment: if we look at the Dcokerfile in the docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/layers/openwrtorg/rootfs/19.07.4/images/sha256-ab563374f7b7b5dd26ef96a2b181f5f722cdbceae16a3e7dfffc7d16749fd34a?context=explore there is no FROM statement, further the ADD statement in this link is not understandabe, can you help me with that?

Comment: @VikrantChauhan I am not sure but I think that is the ID for the scratch image. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10737